# Collect values by internal numbering while taking into account the seconds between them

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a Data Frame that looks like this:

```
Answers,all_answers,Score
1.0,1,1
0.0,0,1
0.0,0,2
0.0,0,3
-1.0,1,1
0.0,0,1
0.0,0,2
1.0,1,1
-1.0,1,2
0.0,0,1
1.0,1,1
```

Each line is a second

The answers column means with which sign the calculation was made at this second: 1 is a positive number -1 is a negative number

The All_Answers column is the answers column modulo that is, without negative signs. It was made for the third column of the internal Score account. Score counts how many times the value 0 or 1 went in a row.

Data Frame can consist of 5000+ rows

And the internal account column of the value 0 can reach an average of 300 values

I want to collect the values of All_answers in a new column with the condition that between them the value 0 did not exceed 5.While observing the Answers sign.

For example

```
Answers,all_answers,Score,New
1.0,1,1,1
0.0,0,1,0
0.0,0,2,0
0.0,0,3,0
0.0,0,4,0
0.0,0,5,0
0.0,0,6,0
-1.0,1,1,0
0.0,0,1,0
0.0,0,2,0
1.0,1,1,1
-1.0,1,2,-1
0.0,0,1,0
1.0,1,1,1
```

There may be such values:

```
Answers,all_answers,Score,New
1.0,1,1,1
0.0,0,1,0
-1.0,1,1,-1
0.0,0,1,0
1.0,1,1,1
0.0,0,1,0
-1.0,1,1,-1
0.0,0,1,0
1.0,1,1,1
0.0,0,1,0
-1.0,1,1,-1
0.0,0,1,0
0.0,0,2,0
1.0,1,1,1
```

And it can be

```
Answers,all_answers,Score,New
0.0,0,19,0
0.0,0,20,0
0.0,0,21,0
0.0,0,22,0
0.0,0,23,0
0.0,0,24,0
0.0,0,25,0
0.0,0,26,0
-1.0,1,1,0
0.0,0,1,0
0.0,0,2,0
0.0,0,3,0
0.0,0,4,0
0.0,0,5,0
0.0,0,6,0
1.0,1,1,0
```

And very rarely can this happen. But this is exactly the aggregate I'm trying to find and I want to see it on the chart.

```
Answers,all_answers,Score,New
1.0,1,1,0
0.0,0,1,0
0.0,0,2,0
0.0,0,3,0
0.0,0,4,0
0.0,0,5,0
-1.0,1,1,-1
1.0,1,2,1
-1.0,1,3,-1
1.0,1,4,1
-1.0,1,5,-1
0.0,0,1
0.0,0,2
0.0,0,3
0.0,0,4
1.0,1,1,1
0.0,0,1
0.0,0,2
0.0,0,3
0.0,0,4
0.0,0,5
0.0,0,6
0.0,0,7
```

I already have a script that finds values that have been in a row five times
That is, he just collects such values but does not see the values that were two seconds later

Here it is

```
    s = np.sign(df['all_answers'])
    group = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
    df['Score'] = s.groupby(group).cumcount().add(1)
    g = df['all_answers'].ne(df['all_answers'].shift()).cumsum()
    X1 = int(x)
    m = df.groupby(g)['all_answers'].transform('size').ge(5)
    df['New'] = df['Answers'].where(m, 0)
```

That's what it outputs

```
Answers,all_answers,Score,New
1.0,1,1,0.0
0.0,0,1,0.0
0.0,0,2,0.0
0.0,0,3,0.0
0.0,0,4,0.0
0.0,0,5,0.0
-1.0,1,1,-1
1.0,1,2,1.0
-1.0,1,3,-1
1.0,1,4,1.0
-1.0,1,5,-1
```

The logic of creating a new column is as follows: that he will collect the values 1 and -1 from Answers between which there is no distance where the Score column has raised 5

Comment: Please explain better the logic behind New column

Comment: Third row from the end in your dataframe is `-1.0,1,2`. Shouldn't it be `-1.0,1,1` ?

Comment: No it is negative because there is also a negative number in the Answers column

Comment: The logic of creating a new column is as follows: that he will collect the values 1 and -1 from Answers between which there is no distance where the Score column has raised 5

Comment: That is, if there is a string 0.0,0,7, and so on, then after it it will not have the value of one if it falls further along the frame

Comment: Question: is it possible for an `1` or `-1` answer to have an associated value in `Score` that is *not* `1`. E.g. could these also have `6` (and then exceed `5`)?

Comment: Yes it can be and they can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, something as follows should work.

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Answers': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: -1, 8: 0, 
                    9: 0, 10: 1, 11: -1, 12: 0, 13: 1}, 
        'all_answers': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 
                        8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 0, 13: 1}, 
        'Score': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 1, 8: 1, 
                  9: 2, 10: 6, 11: 2, 12: 1, 13: 1}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# notice that I've given Answer `1` at index value `10` a Score of `6`. 
# This should *not* affect `New` for the next answer.
print(df.iloc[10:12])
    Answers  all_answers  Score
10        1            1      6
11       -1            1      2
```

**Problem**

Each answer `(-1,1)` in col `Answers` *may* be preceded by one of more rows where `df.Answers == 0`. If, in such an event the preceding rows with `0` contain an associated `Score` value that exceeds `5`, then the *following* answer (so: either `-1` or `1`) should get a `0` in col `New`. In *all* other scenarios, col `New` should simply take the value from col `Answers`.

**Solution**

```
# add col `groups` with each consecutive value in `Answers` as one group
df['groups'] = (df.Answers != df.Answers.shift()).cumsum()

# add col `mask` with 1 for each `Answers` value `(-1,1)`, 
# and the actual df.Score for all `0` vals
df['mask'] = np.where(df.Answers.ne(0),1,df.Score)

# now groupby `groups` and get the max `mask` val for each group,
# check if this val exceeds 5 (`gt(5)`) to get a boolean Series
# we shift the series so that it can be mapped onto the *following* group
# (and we `fillna` for the very first group: 
    # it will always need a `False` (never preceded by `0s` of course))
# finally, we map this result to col `groups`, and use the boolean Series
# inside `np.where` for evaluation. If `False` we want `0`, else `df.Answers`
df['New'] = np.where(
    df['groups'].map(
        df.groupby('groups')['mask'].max().gt(5).shift().fillna(False)),
    0,
    df.Answers)

# drop the temp cols `groups` and `mask`
df.drop(['groups','mask'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)

    Answers  all_answers  Score  New
0         1            1      1    1
1         0            0      1    0
2         0            0      2    0
3         0            0      3    0
4         0            0      4    0
5         0            0      5    0
6         0            0      6    0
7        -1            1      1    0
8         0            0      1    0
9         0            0      2    0
10        1            1      6    1
11       -1            1      2   -1
12        0            0      1    0
13        1            1      1    1
```

Check:

```
print(df.loc[df.Answers.ne(0)])

    Answers  all_answers  Score  New
0         1            1      1    1
7        -1            1      1    0
10        1            1      6    1
11       -1            1      2   -1
13        1            1      1    1
```

So, all answers should be OK in `New`, except `-1` at index value `7`, since this is preceded by consecutive `0` rows with a value exceeding `5`, namely:

```
print(df.iloc[1:8])

   Answers  all_answers  Score  New
1        0            0      1    0
2        0            0      2    0
3        0            0      3    0
4        0            0      4    0
5        0            0      5    0
6        0            0      6    0
7       -1            1      1    0
```